# Why NSArray have the method indexOfObjectPassingTest and not objectsPassingTest like NSSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsset

**NSArray** have ***indexOfObjectPassingTest*** method however with **NSSet** you can get directly the object by using the method ***objectsPassingTest***.

I know, is trivial get the object form a **NSArray** given the index, but you have to code it :), and of course in **NSSet** you don't have indexes so it must return an Object.

So the question is why this datatypes have different methods for the same task (find an element by passing some test) instead of implement ***objectsPassingTest***?.

Comment: @danh made a good point about `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`. (I've deleted the answer that he commented on, because I think his comment was better than my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why an analogy isn't present in `NSArray`.  Perusing the docs, quite a few collection methods have a polymorphic twin, but not this one.

[`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1411033-filteredarrayusingpredicate?language=objc) might suit most problems well enough, but to match the `NSSet` signature, it wouldn't be unreasonable to extend `NSArray` like this:

```
// NSArray+NotUnreasonableAddition.h
@interface NSArray (NotUnreasonableAddition)
- (NSArray *)objectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id, BOOL *))test; 
@end

// NSArray+NotUnreasonableAddition.m
@implementation NSArray (NotUnreasonableAddition)

- (NSArray *)objectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id, BOOL *))test {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (id obj in self) {
        BOOL stop = NO;
        if (test(obj, &stop)) [result addObject:obj];
        if (stop) break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because going from index to object is trivial, but going from object to index isn't.